# Automatically add files to a newly created GIT Branch

Tags: git, github, workflow, cicd

I am trying to automate a task in my GitHub repository whenever a new branch is created.

The task is:

- Adding a few files automatically as soon as a new branch is created.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: That makes no sense. GitHub only ever sees files that you added locally, committed and pushed to the server. Or do you want to generate these files in the gh ci and add and commit them atop of the new branch's HEAD?

Comment: @MarcusMüller this is more for keeping some custom configuration.. Is it not possible to have it via any hook / workflows/ CICD?

Comment: I don't understand. Please answer the question I asked in my first comment!

Comment: Ok, now I see your edited comment.
Yes, you are correct. It is like adding a commit on top of the new branch's HEAD, using GH CI. As I have to add few configuration files continuously to all my repositories.

Comment: Then you would write a workflow entry in the .github/workflows file, right?

Comment: Git is a a set of tools, not a solution. It's also an *extensible* set of tools, so if you want a special tool ("create branch and add some files") you *write that tool*. What problems are you having with your attempt to write this tool?

Comment: Is there a way to trigger a workflow that is not part of the branch of the PR? For example, I am keeping my workflows under `main-workflow` branch and if I raise a PR for a merge between `develop-new_branch1` from `feature-new-branch1`. I would want my main-workflow's github action to get triggered for every PR that is raised without those branches having the github/workflows. How can this be achieved?